# Irregular shape 3D solid: some useful book on theory behind 3D direct modelling.

Tags: geometry, 3d, mathematical-modeling

I'm a senior mechanical engineer that design pressure vessels for petrochemical use.

Very often I have to check mass and centroids of irregural shape objects since my drafters are not skill enough to use 3D geometry, we do not use 3D cad software and my Company ( we prefer to use 2D cad to generate drawing to pass to my workshop for the fabrication activities) and this mass/centroid check is a boring but necessary activity to be performed for each vessel, activity than nobody want to perform.

I am affascinated to the amazing software routines behind generation and modification of 3D objects in commercial 3D cads. Hard to write general pourpose routine (high skill professional activity), but the theory is allways the same! Analitical gemetry! Quaterions, 2D/3D Algebra, Linear Algebra, Vectors and Matrix Operations, multiple variable integration, jacobians, ...

So, Can some one suggest me some books that deal with the generation of 3D solids? More specific in DIRECT MODELLING. I have god skill in math.

I do not want to duplicate a commercial 3D cad .... I wan to to know theory behind and try to write some semplified software or XLS file to get data of simple irregular shape solid to turn easy this check (nozzles, tubesheets, formed heads, transitions with flare and knuckles, support saddles/brackets, trunnions, ....)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Examples
Nozzle 1 [Nozzle1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhA3C.jpg)
Nozzle 2 [Nozzle2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9o6F.jpg)

Comment: 'I have god skill in math' - that's amazing

Comment: On a serious note, you don't really need much of the usual 3d graphics mathematical foundations. Such as 3d rotations - you don't need to rotate you object to compute the centroid, right? This is a very specific task and there are probably very specific routines for it.

Comment: Rotations about a point, change of referency system, ... no ... I have not to do this. With quaterions and matrix operation it is "easy". The problem is generation of 3D solids I do not know how generate a irregular solid ... how it is conposed with.

Comment: @ Ganfoss depeds on the shape and the accuracy you need. Look at computer games, if the models are complicated, they are approximated by polygons

Comment: @Ganfoss, I find it very strange how you can create irregular 3D shapes using 2D drawings only. There must be something you're not telling us about this process. Are the shapes, for example, axially symmetric? Or do the 2D drawings represent cross sections at different locations? Knowing that, it might be possible to give you better advise regarding your ultimate purpose, rather than just references to books on the overall subject...

Comment: @NominalAnimal -- people were manufacturing irregular 3D objects from 2D drawings for decades before 3D CAD systems were invented, and many people continue to work this way. The drawing (together with human intelligence) has enough information to describe the shape of the object. This is typically through the use of multiple views and cros-sections.

Comment: @bubba: Completely irregular shapes are very difficult to draft, especially when there are complementary features that make reading the blueprints correctly very hard (because it requires quite a good skill in mental 3D visualization). I do believe manufacturing in parts, and scale models, have been regularly used for complicated irregular parts because of this. I am just not convinced that a successful business producing irregular 3D objects can rely on 2D drawings alone; either the description of the workflow is incomplete, or there is a lot of hidden knowledge (experience) in the process.

Comment: @NominalAnimal -- you threw in the word "completely", which might change the answer. Highly sculptured shapes like car bodies, ship hulls, and turbine blades are difficult to describe by 2D drawings.  But, people did it -- cars and ships were around long before 3D CAD systems. And, anyway, the OP's parts are really not very "irregular", they are mostly just intersecting circular cylinders. OTOH, I think 3D CAD modeling is really the best approach, for all but the simplest parts. It has many benefits, including making me a large pile of money over the past 4 decades.

Comment: @bubba: I'm just a hobbyist, but I do prefer old-style 2D drafting the difficult details of my ideas. (Would love an architect's table.) My point was that with additional information on the objects at hand, we could provide better, more focused advice. OP's edit is informative. So, say, an outline curve to define the initial axially symmetric shape, followed by (negative) solid geometry operations using axially symmetric shapes (spheres, cylinders, and cones). That is a very small subset of the vast subject domain, and would let the OP to focus on immediately practically applicable info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good books about solid modeling written by Chris Hoffman and Martti Mäntylä. I can't remember whether they cover the specific topic of calculating volumes. Here are the references:

[Introduction to Solid Modeling -- Martti Mäntylä](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716780151)

[Geometric and Solid Modeling -- Christoph Hoffman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0063O85X6)

You could also read the code of an open source solid modeler, like OpenCascade.

To compute mass properties, you will probably need to construct a 3D model.  You may as well do this in a 3D CAD system, and then you can use the CAD system's functions to do the computations.

If you really want to do the computations yourself, you could start by reading some of the following:

- Y. T. Lee and A. A. G. Requicha. Algorithms for computing the volume
  and other integral properties of solids. I. Known methods and
  open issues. Communications of the ACM, 25(9):635–641, 1982.
- Y. T. Lee and A. A. G. Requicha. Algorithms for computing the volume
  and other integral properties of solids. II. A family of algorithms
  based on representation conversion and cellular approximation. Communications
  of the ACM, 25(9):642–650, 1982.
- B. Mirtich. Fast and accurate computation of polyhedral mass properties.
  Journal of Graphics Tools, 1(2):31–50, 1996.
- O. Soldea, G. Elber, and E. Rivlin. Exact and efficient computation
  of moments of free-form surface and trivariate based geometry.
  Computer-Aided Design, 34(7):529–539, 2002.
- H. Timmer and J. Stern. Computation of global geometric properties
  of solid objects. Computer-Aided Design, 12(6):301–304, 1980.

Comment: Dear alls,
here there are some picture that show an example of "Irregular Shape 3D Solid" that I have to get Weight and Centroid:

- Example 1 [FlangedButWeld](http://www.woihouston.com/uploads/7/2/1/5/7215847/131643.jpg)

- Example 2 [SetInNozzle](http://www.woihouston.com/uploads/7/2/1/5/7215847/184517.jpg)

Example 1 is easyto draft in 2D: I have to draft in 2D  drawings two perpendicular sections with teh cutting plane passing strough nozzle centerline/axis.

Example 2 is not easy to show in a 2D drawing: I need to report more INFO on a 2D Drawing to allow its construction.

Comment: @ Yuri: I have discovered a lot of MATH behind Gaming Modelling ... not an easy work the modelling! I presume that Polygonal Surfaces that envelope my 3D solid it is not the right way to deal with my job (I have not to show on a videa like in a CAD, but get its mass and centroid).

Comment: I was not able to get the title of  a book written by  Chris Hoffmann or Marti Mantylla.

Comment: Very interesting links! (As a fellow Finn, I must point out that the name is *Martti Mäntylä*, though.) @Ganfoss: Can you assume uniform density, i.e. a single material used?

Comment: If density is not uniform, the problem is somewhat harder, of course. Most CAD systems and most research papers (including the ones I listed) assume uniform density.